# Unable to find the current binding

Tags: simplesamlphp

[image]

What Im missing?

-No SAML response provided

-You accessed the Assertion Consumer Service interface, but did not provide a SAML Authentication Response. Please note that this endpoint is not intended to be accessed directly.

Comment: You need to provide some more context. Perhaps use SAML tracer and see what is in the response from your IdP?